# Divide Array into 2 equal sum parts using only one loop, need alternative approach

Tags: java, data-structures, logic

Usually what we do is 
1.we calculate sum of whole array from left and call it Leftsum
2.then we starts traversing array from Right end and start adding 
  every element into RIGHTSUM, and subracting every element from 
  LEFTSUM
3. untill LEFTSUM=RIGHTSUM,then we assign current value of iterator 
   variable  I to splitpoint
4.Now array before SPLITPOINT index and from SPLITPOINT index to end have equal sum

MAIN PROBLEM------>

but this will work if array is ((3 , 5 , 10) , (3, 10 , 5)) but not on  (3 , 5 , 5 , 3, 10 , 10) because we cannot find SPLITPOINT here whose left and right array sum is equal

answer of second part should also be (3,5,10) (5,3,10)
Again sum of 2 parts should be equal not length
this is an easy illustation example above

Comment: In general it's not possible to partition an array into two parts with an equal sum. Is such a partition guaranteed to exist in your case? Why?

Comment: Only sum should be equal not array length

Comment: Still, it's not possible in general. Consider (1, 3, 9).

Comment: that's basic things that array elements will be entered in such a manner that 2 equal sum with using these array elements are possible
consider my second example (3 , 5 , 5 , 3, 10 , 10) 

yes obviously programm will print not possible if array element's sum cannot be divided into 2 equal sums

Comment: so for what purpose u want to divide the array?can u explain that@Umesh Pathak

Comment: @sandhiya Just a competitive programming question asked in interviews

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the total for the whole sequence is N. You're effectively looking for a sub-sequence that sums to N/2. (Note: if N is odd, there is no such sub-sequence!)

This is the "subset sum" problem. There's a decent Java solution for that at [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum).